# After change some code, should i restart the Android Emulator?

Tags: android, android-emulator

I have opened the Android Emulator for my first set of code change. Then later i change some of my code. Should i want to close the emulator and relaunch (re-run) the code to reflect my new changes? or else simply pressing run key in eclipse will reflect the changes?

Please clarify.

PS : Till now, i wont close and relaunch the emulator for every code change. But today i faced the error in console like "Application already running, uninstall the application and try". That's why i have doubt on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to relaunch the emulator, pressing the Run button in Eclipse will work.

When you receive a message similar to this one:

```
Re-installation failed due to different application signatures.
You must perform a full uninstall of the application. WARNING: ...This will remove the application data!
Please execute 'adb uninstall com.antew.code' in a shell.
```

Open a command prompt and use:

```
adb uninstall <package name>
```

e.g.

```
adb uninstall com.antew.code
```

Then relaunch the application from Eclipse to install it again.  The adb exe is in the /platform-tools/ folder of the SDK.

Answer (score 0):

no need to close the emulator at all .............

the message is due to as some time application is in front (running) emulator denys to re-run . For this just simply close the app by back button and run from eclipse

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to restart the emulator for a code change -- simply "Run"ning it from Eclipse does the trick. I think the reason you're getting that error is that you're trying to run it with no code changes.

Answer (score 0):

Don't restart your emulator for every changes made. Just deploy your application on the emulator.

If you won't face the `Application already running, uninstall the application and try`be sure that your application is not started in the emulator.

If it is,just switch to another ativity and then try deploy your application.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to restart the emulator!!!

You simply need to run youe application again from eclipse(Ctrl + F11). If you have done any changes in code(and saved them all) then on running the application you will get output something like below

```
[2013-06-19 13:19:12 - MyFirstApp] ------------------------------
[2013-06-19 13:19:12 - MyFirstApp] Android Launch!
[2013-06-19 13:19:12 - MyFirstApp] adb is running normally.
[2013-06-19 13:19:12 - MyFirstApp] Performing com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity activity launch
[2013-06-19 13:19:12 - MyFirstApp] Automatic Target Mode: using existing emulator 'emulator-5554' running compatible AVD 'Micromax_A_68'
[2013-06-19 13:19:12 - MyFirstApp] Uploading MyFirstApp.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
[2013-06-19 13:19:14 - MyFirstApp] Installing MyFirstApp.apk...
[2013-06-19 13:19:26 - MyFirstApp] Success!
[2013-06-19 13:19:26 - MyFirstApp] Starting activity com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity on device emulator-5554
[2013-06-19 13:19:28 - MyFirstApp] ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.example.myfirstapp/.MainActivity
```

Above logs are specific to my app but you get the point... If you have no changes saved then you will get some additional output lines as follows

```
...
[2013-06-19 13:22:10 - MyFirstApp] Application already deployed. No need to reinstall.
...
```